# nodeJS: Sending html data from one js to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below is working

```
var express = require('express')
var app =  express();
var fs = require('fs')
var addUserToDB = require('./addUserToDB')

app.use('addUserToDB', addUserToDB)

app.get('/register.html', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/" + "register.html");
})

var server = app.listen(8087,function(){

    console.log("Listening at 8087");
})


app.get('/addUserToDB',function(req,res){

    firstname = req.query.firstname;
    console.log(firstname)
})

app.get('/register.html', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/" + "register.html");
})
```

However, when I try to remove the following method and place it into another .js file so I can get the firstName from that file. It's not working. The following code is in addUserToDB.js:

```
var addUserToDB = app.get('/addUserToDB',function(req,res){

        firstname = req.query.firstname;
        console.log(firstname)
    })
module.exports = addUserToDB;
```

I have tried making a addUserToDB.js file and added the code

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.get('addUserToDB',function(req,res){

    firstname = req.query.firstname;
    console.log(firstname)
})
```

but it seems I am missing something because it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: did you "require" the new file in your main server.js?

Comment: yes i have this: `module.exports = addUserToDB;` in my addUserToDB.js and also the following: `var addUserToDB = require('./addUserToDB')

app.use('addUserToDB', addUserToDB)` in server.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here. First, need to do a `require` of `addUserToDB.js` from `server.js` (I will assume that's the name of your main file) and then use it as a middleware. Also, you need to export the app from `addUserToDB.js`.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var app =  express();
var fs = require('fs')
var addUserToDB = require('./addUserToDB');

app.get('/register.html', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/" + "register.html");
})

var server = app.listen(8087,function(){

    console.log("Listening at 8087");
})

app.use(addUserToDB);
```

addUserToDB.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/addUserToDB',function(req,res){

    firstname = req.query.firstname;
    console.log(firstname)
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: it's working thank you. I want to ask this: when you are doing `module.exports = app;` what, am i right in understanding that you are importing all usages of `app` in `addUserToDB.js` ?... and also, is there a way to export the entire file instead of a var or a function of a file?

Comment: Yes, you can say it like that. You're exporting the definition of the functions in your file, which in this case is `app` plus the route for `/addUserToDB`. Alternatively, you can use `var router = express.Router();` instead of `var app = express();` (and `router` instead of `app`) and you will achieve the same effect, but using Express's router is better than using `app` because you only export the route and not the whole app.

Comment: No, you can only export one variable. If you need to add more routes to `addUserToDB.js` you can call define more routes like `router.get('/route')` before exporting `route` (or `app`). Or in some cases, for controllers, you can just export an object with functions, like `module.exports = { func1: function () { }, func2: function () {}};`.

Comment: so its like the entire code inside a `.js` file belongs to a module.exports? - @Luiz

Comment: That would be the optimal way to do it. If you're separating your app into several modules or files, each module should do specifically one thing, so anything you do in a file and export should be related to the same thing.

Comment: Yes that's the exact reason for me to ask this question, modularity is the better way to do this. Separation of concern is the goal here. Thanks :)